# Is answer from teacher announcing potential consequences considered rude?

Tags: discussion, rude-or-abusive

Is an answer like the following considered rude? I already flagged the post as low quality as there is no way that the answer can be fixed. However I feel that even if the CS department has this internal policy, such an answer on SO might be considered threatening as there is an implicit threat in the answer. Personally I feel uncomfortable with any answer that implies that the person asking has to face consequences outside of SO.

> Remember, you should always ask the forum help section or email the professor instead of asking on sites like this. Consider this your first and final warning.

For reference this answer is from https://stackoverflow.com/a/46439822/553596

Comment: I'm not sure I would go as far as it being rude, but it is certainly not an answer.

Comment: Also worth noting that this account was only created today.  This makes me question whether this is really the university.

Comment: @JoeC Does it really make a difference whether the account was created by the university (or a professor/teaching assistant) or not? I think neither we nor the author of the question can be sure and as a result can assume that the **"Consider this your first and final warning."** is legit (or at least can be interpreted as legit by us and the author of the question).

Comment: For the purpose of how we moderate this site, no, it doesn't make a difference whether it really is the university or not.

Comment: Posting non-answers to questions is borderline abusive behavior, but we already have a flag for that: "not an answer". Don't overthink it.

Comment: Why would anyone construe this as rude or abusive unless they were a delinquent student with complete disregard for the rules anyway? An academic warning is nowhere near the same thing as, say, a threat of violence.

Comment: The world gets a lot darker when you start to call simple informative warnings a "threat". Let's not overstate things and keep it grounded. There is no reason not to believe this is just a teacher trying to reach a student (or more likely: a group of students) through an improper communication channel and prevent them from flunking out.

Comment: The only thing rude is the comment on that answer stating they should delete their account.

Comment: My sentiments exactly, @CodeCaster.

Comment: Well, plagiarizing the teacher's work and copying it without permission is pretty rude.  Somebody initiates it and then it is escalating tit for tat from there, happens all the time.  Remarkable btw how insta-deleting a homework question is now suddenly possible.  We'll have lots more use for that in the next 8 weeks, it's going to be hell.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

It's definitely *not* an answer, and should be flagged as such.  Regardless of if they actually have influence or power at this institution is somewhat immaterial as far as we're concerned.

Don't be surprised that higher education institutions monitor this site for questions like this.  They want to put an end to plagiarism as much as we do, and it's not unheard of for them to leave comments or answers behind as a way to inform the student that they're walking a *thin* line.

Definitely not an answer though, regardless of the intent.

Comment: Many professors and TAs aren't as familiar with the Q&A system of Stack Overflow, so it's not surprising that they'd leave non-answers like this when they find they can't comment. Maybe a quarter of the time, it's not actually a professor but a student from their class trying to troll and scare them. Unless the post is a direct insult or personal threat, I don't consider someone informing a student about the consequences of violating an honor code to be offensive. Clearly not an answer to the question asked, though.

Comment: You'd think a professor would be capable of reading the site rules and getting enough rep to comment quite easily though.

Comment: A bit off-topic, but I am impressed that a CS institution does not allow asking in SO. SO is considerably more strict in the quality of questions that we accept than anyone else. We just shut down effortless questions, so if the question is good for SO, then my opinion is that a professor should be OK with them posting it. I have answered several questions of my students in SO, and I am actually happy they asked